# Swap a chars bits and replace it with the new created char after swaps

Tags: c, char, swap, bit

I'm attempting to swap two bit values in a char.  I've dived into this and my code is fairly confusing at this point.  I have a nested for loop, one going through an array of chars, looking at each char, putting the bits of a single char into an array, performing some swaps, and finally setting the current char, (location in the char array) to the int array.

I was hoping that I could just update the current char, (in the char array) to the int arrays bit value, making the new char.

Basically, the goal is to swap bits in a char and produce a new char.

my declared variables...

```
unsigned char s = 's';
FILE *fp;
char ch;
int count = 0;

//used in a loop to create an array of chars
unsigned char *load = malloc(sizeof(char)); 
int i = 0;
char temp, temp2;
int temp3, temp4;
int w, v;
int array[7];

v = 0;
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
   {
   for (w = 7; w >= 0; w--)
      {
      array[v] = (1 & (load[i] >> w));
      }

   temp3 = array[5];
   array[5] = array[1];
   array[1] = temp3;

   temp4 = array[0];
   array[0] = array[4];
   array[4] = temp4;

   //here I'm trying to set a char array to an int array.
   //would static casting the int array to char work?  
   //I can't find a way to convert it.
   load[i] = array;
   }
```

I'm trying to perform this swap for every byte in an array of unsigned chars.

Thanks for your time, it's deeply appreciated.

EDIT: Posting the entire piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

//unsigned char *s = "S";
unsigned char s = 's';
FILE *fp;
char ch;
int count = 0;
unsigned char *load = malloc(sizeof(char));
int i = 0;
char temp, temp2;
int temp3, temp4;
int w, v;
int array[7];

v = 0;

fp = fopen("file", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{   
    perror("Exiting, an error occured\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}

//print encrypted file

while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", ch);
    ++count;
}


fclose(fp);

printf("\n\n");

fp = fopen("file", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("exiting\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

i = 0;

//load encrypted file into usigned char array   
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    load[i++] = ch;
}

load[i] = 0;
fclose(fp);

//print unsigned char array in hex
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    printf("%x ", load[i]);
}   

printf("\nNext\n");

//print unsigned char array
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    printf("%c ", load[i]);
}       
printf("\n\n"); 


//byte swaps through every 4th byte in the unsignged char array until end   
for (i = 3; i < count;)
{
    temp = load[i-1];
    load[i-1] = load[i];
    load[i] = temp;
    i = i + 4;
}

//print new unsigned char array
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    printf("%c ", load[i]);
}       
printf("\n\n"); 

//bit swaps on every byte in the unsigned char array
//not working
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    for (w = 7; w >= 0; w--)
    {
        array[v] = (1 & (load[i] >> w));
    }

    temp3 = array[5];
    array[5] = array[1];
    array[1] = temp3;

    temp4 = array[0];
    array[0] = array[4];
    array[4] = temp4;

    load[i] = array;

}

//XOR every 4th byte in the unsigned char array
for (i = 3; i < count;)
{
    temp = (load[i-1] ^ s);
    temp2 = (load[i] ^ s);
    load[i-1] = temp;
    load[i] = temp2;
    i = i + 4;
}       

//print the decrypted message
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    printf("%c ", load[i]);
}       
printf("\n\n"); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI sizeof(char) is always 1

Comment: `for (w = 0; w >= 0; w--)` - strange "loop". Strange comment on the malloc, that won't ever create an array of more than one char. You can't assign to arrays, but I really can't tell from your code what that assignment is supposed to do.

Comment: I updated the post to show you how I'm using it to create an array of chars.

Comment: in the loop w should have been set to 7, it reads correctly now.

Comment: @user3586343, It appears that you are under the misconception that 'malloc()' zero's out the allocated memory?  However, 'malloc()' does not zero out the memory.  Hence, 'load' will point to memory with random content (not a nice-zeroed-out array).  Hence, the value resulting from the expression '(1 & (load[i] >> w))' will be unpredictable.

Comment: so when reading in data from a file I should allocate the size of the array to put it into with a count?  Count how many chars are in it and set the array size equal to that?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to swap bits .you can try this(swap first bit with second bit):

```
int i=13; //13=1101
c ^= 3;   //3=0011,c=1110
```

with bit-operation '^',you can turn 1 to 0,turn 0 to 1,which can solve your problem.

Comment: I have an 8 bit byte and I'm attempting to switch bit 6 with bit 2.  Could I just convert the char to the 8 bits, preform the swap, then convert back by taking 2^7, 2^6, 2^5, 2^4, 2^3, 2^2, 2^1, 2^0 for the decimal #, then take that # and take the hex value.

Comment: if you want to switch bit 6 with bit 2,you should use:c ^= 221;//221=1101 1101

Comment: if you have problems with bit-operation,you can read this:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_XOR_.22.5E.22

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand, for example if I wanted to swap bits 5 and 1, I would use c ^= 228

Comment: i apologize for my above mistake,if you want to switch bit 6 with bit 2,you should use:c ^= 34.if you want to swap bits 5 and 1, you should use c ^= 17.